# How can I know where my spooled file is located?

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

I am using a java program to call a CL program from as400 that generates a spooled file that is to be retrieved. I do not know where the generated spooled file is. Where is it located?

I tried finding it using wrkjob with the same number, user, and name to the job that created the spooled file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that in this scenario, a host server job which has swapped from the default QUSER profile to the user ID you've connected with...the IBM i generates the spool file in a separate job named QPRTJOB running under the user ID you used to connect.

So you should see the spool file as one of your own, using any standard methods such as `WRKSPLF USER(*CURRENT)`

You should also be able to find it via `WRKJOB JOB(your-user-profile/QPRTJOB) OPTION(*SPLF)`

If you don't see a spool file, either it didn't get created, or it got printed (and your system is configured to delete after printing.)

This issue normally bites people when they have an existing process that creates a spool file and the converts it to PDF for instance and emails it.  Since the spool file ends up created in a different job, the conversion process doesn't find it since most are looking for the spool file created in the current job.

In that case, one option is to modify the process to use the Retrieve Identity of Last Spooled File Created (QSPRILSP) API

Here's some IBM documentation about this issue..
[Finding and Working with Spooled Files Generated under a QPRTJOB Job](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/643699)